# How to get byte[] atributte with PODAM

Tags: java, jemos-podam

I found this useful library [PODAM](http://home.btconnect.com/jemosAgile/projects/podam/index.html), but I troubles to get automatic byte Array. I used implemented AttributeStrategy

```
public class LogoStrategy implements AttributeStrategy<byte[]>{

private static final int MAX_SIZE_FILE = 512*1024;

  @Override
  public byte[] getValue() throws PodamMockeryException {
    byte[] b = new byte[20];
    new Random().nextBytes(b);
    return b;
  }

}
```

but when I used I got this Error:

```
2014-10-21 20:13:04 PodamFactoryImpl [ERROR] The type of the Podam Attribute 
Strategy is not java.lang.String but [B. An exception will be thrown.

Exception in thread "main" uk.co.jemos.podam.exceptions.PodamMockeryException: An illegal argument was passed
at uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufacturePojoInternal(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1569)
at uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufacturePojo(PodamFactoryImpl.java:129)
at uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufacturePojo(PodamFactoryImpl.java:119)
at cl.molavec.jpa.entities.singleton.QuotationPropertiesSingleton.getNewInstance(QuotationPropertiesSingleton.java:26)
at cl.molavec.main.InsertDummyData.main(InsertDummyData.java:66)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type of the Podam Attribute Strategy is not java.lang.String but [B. An exception will be thrown.
at uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.returnAttributeDataStrategyValue(PodamFactoryImpl.java:2888)
at uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufacturePojoInternal(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1493)
... 4 more
```

I implemented AttributeStrategy but with char[] attribute and all nice. The error I couldn't understand why is expecting a String.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you try to use?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you attached `@PodamStrategyValue` annotation to the String field.

```
@PodamStrategyValue(LogoStrategy.class)
String myAttribute;
```

Since `LogoStrategy` returns `byte[]` it cannot be assigned to String, hence the exception.

Either change field type to `byte[]`

```
@PodamStrategyValue(LogoStrategy.class)
byte[] myAttribute;
```

or make `LogoStrategy` to return String

```
public class LogoStrategy implements AttributeStrategy<String>{

    private static final Random rnd = new Random();

    @Override
    public String getValue() throws PodamMockeryException {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[20];
        rnd.nextBytes(bytes);
        return DataTypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes);
    }
}
```